# I have below python code and Im facing error 'AttributeError: 'Difference' object has no attribute 'maximumDifference''

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Difference:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__elements = a

    # Add your code here
    def computeDifference(self):
        self.__elements = a
        max_value = a[0]
        min_value = a[0]
        for i in range(1, len(a)):
            min_value = min(min_value, a[i])
            max_value = max(max_value, a[i])

        maximumDifference = max_value - min_value
        # return maximumDifference


# End of Difference class

_ = input("enter")
a = [int(e) for e in input("enter").split(' ')]

d = Difference(a)
d.computeDifference()

print(d.maximumDifference)
```

Comment: `d.maximumDifference` means *maximumDifference* is an attribute of the class *Difference* so you need to set it doing `self.maximumDifference = max_value - min_value`

Answer (score 1):

`maximumDifference = max_value - min_value` should be `self.maximumDifference = max_value - min_value`

Comment: please even this is true please do not just put code to solve but explain whay the problem occurred/why your answer correct it, do that each time you answer

Comment: Sure.. I uploaded for the first time and I was not sure how to post it.From next time I will make sure to explain exact issue

Comment: @SwathiBJ I was speaking to Insignt ^^